# Почему при запуске программы просто спамится индекс искомого числа? Как сделать так чтобы программа выдала одно число?

Tags: массивы, arraylist

```
        public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
   ArrayList<Integer>gg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       gg.add(1);
       gg.add(2);
       gg.add(3);
       gg.add(4);
       gg.add(5);
       gg.add(6);
       gg.add(7);
       gg.add(8);
       gg.add(9);
       gg.add(10);
       gg.add(11);
      int number=5;
      int x=0;
      int a=0;
      int b=gg.size()-1;
     while(a<=b){
        x=(a+b)/2;
       if(gg.get(x)==number){
       System.out.print(x);
       }
       if(number>gg.get(x)){
        a=x+1;
       }
       if(number<gg.get(x)){
        b=x-1;
       }
     }
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) Укажите в тегах язык программирования, на котором написан код. 2) Приведите в вопросе, то что вы ожидаете увидеть после завершения программы  и что у вас выводиться сейчас.

Comment: А вообще просто после вывода добавьте `break`. Т.к. если вы нашли число в массиве, то ни `a`, ни `b` у вас больше не изменяться и начнется бесконечный цикл с выводом одного числа.